# Rails: detect valid student email address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

So, in my app I'd like to offer student discounts.

I use Devise for authentication, and I require confirmation of email addresses. I was thinking that I could just check if the email ends in .edu after it's confirmed, and if yes offer the discount. However, I wonder if that's too simplistic. Is there a list or database of "real" .edu institutions out there, something I could check against?

Does my approach make sense, or would you solve this problem an entirely different way?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To [register a .edu domain](http://net.educause.edu/edudomain/) you must be [eligible](http://net.educause.edu/edudomain/eligibility.asp). This means adding a [validator](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html) on your email address for `/\.edu$/` is sufficient for US educational discounts. This doesn't mean you are reaching only student populations -- research institutions and educators will also get the discount.

Also keep in mind that this will only cover US educational institutions. Australia uses `.edu.au`, the UK uses `.ac.uk`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

just send a confirmation email to the edu address like everybody else does. and they click on a link with a token when they receive the mail. if its correct, you will know.

devise already supports that

Comment: I know Devise supports that, I clearly stated above that this is what I intend to do currently. My question is, is that enough, or is there a *gotcha* I'm not thinking about.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't be able to use the same method, simply because where I live and work, schools/universities have no such domain name convention as .edu.

Solution A: I would use a white list of domains that are universities/schools. I would initially add as many large universitiy/school domainsas possible to that list.  *.edu should be one of them (and all other national edu domains).

When a user sign up I would ask if she/he is a student. If her/his email address includes an unknown domain I would have to review it. :-(

Solution B: Or, I would probably use a checkbox "I am a student" and if that is checked, I would give the discount. If I find that the discount is missused, I would go for solution A or someting similiar.

Comment: Good suggestions Stefan, I'm probably going to incorporate some of what you said in addition to what sj26 suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a list to check for edu. If it's edu, it's certainly not a spammer. Not anybody can get an edu domain :) Unless the scammer owns a school, that hands out certified degrees recognized by the US educational system :P

Comment: Spammers these days, you never know, :)

Comment: lool, the things they will do :D